# Called method output differs from Caller

Tags: java

This program checks every combination of inputArray and prints it -

**Checker.java -**

```
package testpj;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Checker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] subarrayA = {"A0","A1","A2"};

    String[] subarrayB = {"B0","B1"};
    String[] subarrayC = {"C0","C1","C2","C3"};
    String[][] inputArray = {subarrayA, subarrayB, subarrayC};
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    String output1 = permute(inputArray, 0, output);
    System.out.println("the output1: "+output1);
}

public static String permute(String array[][], int index, ArrayList<String> output){

    if(index == array.length){
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0 ; i<array[index].length ; i++){
            output.add(array[index][i]);
            permute(array,index+1,output);
            output.remove(output.size() - 1); 
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[A0, B0, C0]
[A0, B0, C1]
[A0, B0, C2]
[A0, B0, C3]
[A0, B1, C0]
[A0, B1, C1]
[A0, B1, C2]
[A0, B1, C3]
[A1, B0, C0]
[A1, B0, C1]
[A1, B0, C2]
[A1, B0, C3]
[A1, B1, C0]
[A1, B1, C1]
[A1, B1, C2]
[A1, B1, C3]
[A2, B0, C0]
[A2, B0, C1]
[A2, B0, C2]
[A2, B0, C3]
[A2, B1, C0]
[A2, B1, C1]
[A2, B1, C2]
[A2, B1, C3]
the output1: []
```

Why is output1 contains no element ?

Comment: every time you add an element to `output`, you also remove one. So of course it will end up empty.

Comment: It's working exactly as intended from the way you've coded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is when I call permute recursively then it re-initializes the value of output again and so we end up having no value in the output variable. I added one more variable to the permute method and added the output to it instead of adding the output to output itself and it worked.

**Solution:**

```
 public ArrayList<String> permute(String array[][], 
 int index, ArrayList<String> output, ArrayList<String> comb){
        if(index == array.length){
            comb.add(output.toString());            
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0 ; i<array[index].length ; i++){
                output.add(array[index][i]);
                permute(array,index+1,output, comb);
                output.remove(output.size() - 1); 
            }
        }

        return comb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In every round, you add something to the `output`, call the recursive step, and the you **remove** the last item.

This means that if you started with zero items in the `output`, that's what you'll end up with - a zero-length `ArrayList`.

The prints from the recursive calls themselves are done before the item is removed. But the print at the end is of this empty `ArrayList`. This is why the outputs differ.